# How to convert results from sunset and sunrise data using astral package into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I'm trying to find a way to convert my results I got from calculating the dawn and dusk times from a certain time interval using the `astral` package at a certain city into a dataframe. The problem is that once I got the results of the sunrise and sunset information, I have a hard time converting it into a dataframe for further analysis. My code is shown below right now

```
from astral import *

def get_astral_summary():
  x=print((
    f'Dawn:    {s["dawn"]}\n'
    f'Sunrise: {s["sunrise"]}\n'
    f'Noon:    {s["noon"]}\n'
    f'Sunset:  {s["sunset"]}\n'
    f'Dusk:    {s["dusk"]}\n'
  ))
  return x 

city = LocationInfo("Surrey", "Canada", 'US/Pacific',49.104599,-122.823509)
x =pd.date_range(start="2020-12-09",end="2020-12-11")

for y in x:
  s = sun(city.observer, date=y)
  get_astral_summary()
```

Right now, the way I can see my results is making the function that prints out the results, the output is shown below:

```
Dawn:    2020-12-09 15:16:48.899052+00:00
Sunrise: 2020-12-09 15:54:44.342273+00:00
Noon:    2020-12-09 20:03:37+00:00
Sunset:  2020-12-10 00:13:05.243283+00:00
Dusk:    2020-12-10 00:51:00.107776+00:00

Dawn:    2020-12-10 15:17:44.663065+00:00
Sunrise: 2020-12-10 15:55:43.641196+00:00
Noon:    2020-12-10 20:04:04+00:00
Sunset:  2020-12-11 00:13:01.662368+00:00
Dusk:    2020-12-11 00:51:00.111312+00:00

Dawn:    2020-12-11 15:18:38.380512+00:00
Sunrise: 2020-12-11 15:56:40.604162+00:00
Noon:    2020-12-11 20:04:32+00:00
Sunset:  2020-12-12 00:13:01.168222+00:00
Dusk:    2020-12-12 00:51:02.912291+00:00
```

The question arises: How do I put it into a dataframe where the time is formatted correctly? I noticed when I just called the variable `s`, the data type sort of looks like a dictionary like this shown below:

```
{'dawn': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 11, 15, 18, 38, 380512, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 'dusk': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 12, 0, 51, 2, 912291, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 'noon': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 11, 20, 4, 32, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 'sunrise': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 11, 15, 56, 40, 604162, tzinfo=<UTC>),
 'sunset': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 12, 0, 13, 1, 168222, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

I noticed when I do

```
df = pd.DataFrame([s], columns=s.keys())
```

the dataframe doesnt give me the whole time interval, it only gives me this shown below

```
                              dawn  ...                             dusk
0 2020-12-15 15:21:51.681536+00:00  ... 2020-12-16 00:51:41.956146+00:00

[1 rows x 5 columns]
```

Can anyone provide me some suggestions to tackle this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension from `x`:

```
pd.DataFrame([sun(city.observer, date=z) for z in x])
```

Output:

```
                  dawn              sunrise                 noon  \
0 2020-12-09 15:16:... 2020-12-09 15:54:... 2020-12-09 20:03:...   
1 2020-12-10 15:17:... 2020-12-10 15:55:... 2020-12-10 20:04:...   
2 2020-12-11 15:18:... 2020-12-11 15:56:... 2020-12-11 20:04:...   

                sunset                 dusk  
0 2020-12-10 00:13:... 2020-12-10 00:51:...  
1 2020-12-11 00:13:... 2020-12-11 00:51:...  
2 2020-12-12 00:13:... 2020-12-12 00:51:...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a dataframe with a columns for each data key like you did:

> ```
> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=s.keys())
> ```

2. When you loop and create the data, append the data to your df:

> ```
> for y in x:
>     s = sun(city.observer, date=y)
>     df = df.append(s, ignore_index=True)
> ```

Note: your function `get_astral_summary()` should have s as the parameter, not instead of from outer scope.